# JAX-WS in Java 11 and missing class WebParam$Mode

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-11, java-metro-framework

I'm trying to use the wsimport tool in Java 11.

I've obtained an open-source version of jax-ws from the Metro project of Eclipse EE4J, at https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws . I've tried versions 2.3.0 and 2.3.1.

Running wsimport leads to included class [WSDLModeler](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/blob/master/jaxws-ri/tools/wscompile/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/ws/processor/modeler/wsdl/WSDLModeler.java), which includes this import:

```
import javax.jws.WebParam.Mode;
```

Which is not included in the jar files in jaxws-ri, leading to:

```
   [exec] parsing WSDL...
    [exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jws/WebParam$Mode
    [exec]  at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.getParameterOrder(WSDLModeler.java:2585)
    [exec]  at com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.processLiteralSOAPOperation(WSDLModeler.java:779)
    ...
```

There is an implementation of WebParam available in the Jakarta project [jws-api](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jws-api) (Jakarta Web Services Metadata project) -- but under new package name `jakarta.jws.WebParam`.

**Questions**

- Is there a newer replacement for jax-ws that I should be using instead?
- Or is there an implementation of javax.jws.WebParam from elsewhere I should include in the classpath?

Comment: That class is in jsr181-api.jar.  I’m still trying to track down which project builds that jar.

Comment: You might have some luck with the wsimport that comes with [GlassFish](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish).  wsimport itself only uses seven jars in GlassFish’s modules and modules/endorsed directories.

Comment: @VGR - Thanks for the helpful tips. I'm also trying another option - replacing wsimport with Apache CXF's wsdl2java. That works, but the generated code also includes references to the javax.jws package -- so knowing the project that builds that jar would still be useful.

Comment: The package names in the Jakarta project changed [just 24 days ago](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jws-api/pull/51). 
 Until other tools have moved forward to the jakarta package, I think I can pull an earlier release from github.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else encounters the same issue:

- The package names had recently changed in the Jakarta project, and other projects had not yet caught up.
- There were previous releases of the Jakarta project in which the package names were still `javax.jws`.
- The binaries and source for a compatible release (1.1.1) were available on [repo.eclipse.org here](https://repo.eclipse.org/#nexus-search;quick~jws).